# Unable to use custom objects in header files?

Tags: c++, class

I am building a class in a header file (declarations) and a .cpp file (Definitions). In the "private" part I have a

```
string m_name
```

The compiler gives me an error when I try to compile it. If I replace the string with a char* it works fine. I do, however, need a string, not a char*. Should I add the string header somewhere or something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general tip, when you post a question about compiler or linker (or any other) errors, please add the errors you get to your post, it will help immensely. Also please do a verbatim copy of the errors, without any editing or shortening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect two problems: one, "Should I add the string header somewhere?" - you should

```
#include <string>
```

Two, if you're not `using namespace std;`, then you have to use the fully qualified name of the class, which is `std::string` and not just `string`.

Comment: And you don't want to "use namespace std;" in a header since it'll pollute any other file that includes that file.  In headers, use fully qualified namespaces, in cpp files, feel free to use use/using statements.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `#include <string>` at the top of your header file and remember that it's within the `std` namespace: `std::string m_name;`.

Comment: sftrabbit thanks, that fixed it. I didn't know that I also had to add "std ::"

Comment: @Bloodcount Most of the standard library is defined within the `std` namespace. Only macros, `operator new` and `operator delete` aren't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use string, you basically need to include its header file `#include <string.h>` for C or `#include <cstring>` for C++, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: This header will no fix anything, it contains C string utility functions, not std::string class.